# Is there a name for a normal, projective variety where every effective divisor is ample?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, terminology, birational-geometry, intersection-theory

Is there a name for a normal, projective variety such that every effective divisor is ample?  Examples of such varieties are projective space, weighted projective spaces, and simple Abelian varieties [Intersection of subvarieties versus ranks of Chow groups modulo numerical equivalences](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/41619/intersection-of-subvarieties-versus-ranks-of-chow-groups-modulo-numerical-equival).  If someone could also give a reference for the name, I would appreciate it.  Thank you.

Comment: All your examples have Picard group of rank $1$. Conversely, every projective variety with Picard group of rank $1$ has this property.

Comment: In Francesco Polizi's answer in the referenced post he gave an example of such a variety where the Picard number is not one.

Comment: Unless I miss something, the singleton satisfies this, but its Picard group has rank 0.

Comment: For what it's worth, I am not familiar with any such name.

Comment: Any K3 surface that does not contain a smooth rational or elliptic curve is also an example. These surfaces exist for every Picard rank up to 4. The reason these work can be generalized to give more examples.